# How to display data from Woocomerce Api call?

Tags: c#, uwp, woocommerce-rest-api

I have UWP app which downloads data from woocomerce.

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");

WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
//Get all products
var products = await wc.GetOrders();

Debug.WriteLine(products);
```

I try to display data to Console.

Debug shows name of method, how I can show data that I downloaded?

Comment: Really? what you want to see? Do want display data using listview, gridview, what the template? please, explain your problem? where exactly you are stuck? because if you have a problem - we can help you.

Comment: I try to display data to Console. @AndriiKrupka

Comment: It's simple, easy task. I can't imagine that you have a problem with this problem, but I can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's start

```
//Get all products
var products = await wc.GetOrders();
```

You retrieve `OrderList` object type, which derives from `List<Order>`. It means, that you need get data per each item

```
foreach (var order in products)
{

}
```

In `order` item you have all required data, which you need. For example:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Currency: {order.currency}, Total Tax: {order.total_tax}");
```

I hope, you will find way how retrieve other data from `order` item

Comment: Thank's

Yes I find a way how to retrieve other data.