# Get data from woocomerce using WooCommerceNET library

Tags: c#, .net, woocommerce-rest-api

I have successfully connected to my wc site via api, using site_name, customer key and customer secret following the examples on this post: [How to display data from Woocomerce Api call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918908/how-to-display-data-from-woocomerce-api-call)

However I am getting error with this code:

```
 var orders = await wc.Order.GetAll();
```

> "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method..."

I suspect that this is a problem, because I use the code directly in public Form1?

So I have changed the code to (removed "await"):

```
 var orders = wc.Order.GetAll();
```

I try to

```
foreach (var order in orders)
{
     Debug.WriteLine($"ID: {Order.id}");
}
```

The errors here are:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type Task

Why is this marked as "Task"?

This must be so simple to solve, and I feel stupid about it...
Can you help me get un-stuck here?

Thank you HariHaran for helping me solve this issue!
I am now able to successfully read data and write it to textbox etc..

But I can not find a way to read nested data, for example, how do I get the name of category?

```
 "categories": [
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Furniture",
            "slug": "furniture"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a synchronous method ,so change the line like below

```
var orders = wc.Order.GetAll().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Now if you iterate the `orders` it will work.

```
orders.ForEach(o=> Debug.WriteLine($"ID:{o.Id}"));
```

But you should learn about ASYNC / AWAIT - [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)